# Check what table a record belongs in using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to check what table a record belongs in out of 2 tables and set a variable depending on the returned table.

e.g. I have 2 tables (tbl_registered_users, tbl_unregistered_users). If I search for an email address that existed in tbl_registered_users I would like the query to return 'tbl_registered_users' so I can set a variable $whatTable = ... (for example).

I know I could do this with 2 queries or even 1 if I can guarantee the record will exist in at least one table however I would potentially like to use the query on 3/4/5/10 tables and on records that may not exist in any.

Thanks

Comment: How about having a single table with `is_registered` flag?

Comment: Legacy code and I thought about having a single table so it is on the horizon to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `UNION` for that with a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 'Registered' WhichTable, Email
    FROM tbl_registered_users
    UNION 
    SELECT 'UnRegistered', Email
    FROM tbl_unregistered_users 
) t
WHERE Email = 'emailaddress'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26a32/1)

Using `UNION ALL` would yield a better performance, but it won't remove duplicates (in case you have duplicated data in either single table).

Comment: Thanks for the example. Would something like this work if there is an array of email addresses?

Comment: @KerePuki -- np, can you update your example?  An array, something like a comma delimited string (i.e. 'email1,email2,email3')?  If so, perhaps you can use `FIND_IN_SET` instead of `=`.  Something like this: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET (Email,@EmailList)`

Comment: @KerePuki -- np, glad it helped.